# Regular expression that checks repeating characters

Tags: regex

Hi I need help in detecting words that are nonsensical like these: `Okkkk` or `alrrriiigghht`

I found this block of code:

```
var string = "alrrright";
var regex = /(\w)\1+/g;
var res = regex.test(string); 
alert(res);
```

It returns false if it detects that there are no characters that repeats more than once and true if there are any. I need to raise the number of repeated characters. How do I do that? Sorry I really suck at regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `+` with `{n-1,}`, where n is the number of repeated characters:

```
var regex = /(\w)\1{2,}/g;
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IqsbHkMOpko1-8UU)